# Conversion shapefile's coord system from: GCS_Assumed_Geographic_1 to WGS '84

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap

I have my shapefile in ArcMap 10.8.1 with this coordinate system:
Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_Assumed_Geographic_1
Datum:  D_North_American_1927
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree

I want to convert in in WGS 84 but I failed.

I opened one blank map, from view I set WGS 84, I uploaded a basemap, and them from Define projection, I set the coord system to WGS 84, but it did not load correctly.

Any idea?

Ps* maybe it is  ESRI,104000?

Comment: Ten "Assumed" projections and $4 will get you a latte.  Most modern data is *not* in NAD27, so you really need to do research on what the actual coordinate reference is. Using Define Projection when you don't know actual CRS is a mistake, and using Define Projection to Project a dataset is a big mistake.

Comment: @Vince do you have any idea how is it possible to find their actual CRS?

Comment: It's your data. Where did you get it?